# History of assimilation for going to be

Tags: contractions

When did the assimilation of

> *going to be*

into

> *gonna be*

start being used?

Comment: Do you mean in the *written* form, or in *speech*? I wouldn't hold out much hope for the latter being a known (or even, *potentially knowable*) thing. There's probably been a smooth continuum over centuries for the gradual shift in the spoken form.

Answer (score 1):

We have been able to trace "gonna" back to at least 1806<sup>[1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gonna)</sup>.  However, if we compare "gonna" to "shoulda" and other related terms, we can trace it back farther.

In the 1602 Quarto Edition of Mary Wives of Windsor, the character Nym says "I should ha borne the humor Letter to her."<sup>[2](http://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/Annex/Texts/Wiv/Q1/scene/5#tln-670)</sup>  This indicates that "gonna" was likely in use at this time.